# Can't access ENV in Devise Initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Any reason I cant access an ENV variable in my devise.rb initializer. Heres the code inside the file:

```
  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /@.*\b#{ENV.fetch('EMAIL_DOMAIN')}/
```

The ENV 'EMAIL_DOMAIN' is in my .env file along with other variables that I can access without a problem.

Comment: Can you access it through irb console?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon yes i can!

Comment: Where do you load your `.env` file? And will the devise initializer run after that?

Comment: @spickermann in my `docker-compose.yml` file i load it using `env_file: .env`

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the `.env` file being ignored by git, so it isn't getting loaded by docker?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv in your Gemfile :development group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv in your Gemfile :development group it will load your env variables into the Rails app before_configuration callback.

You can then use ENV['MY_VAR'] (or with fetch as you have above) in devise.rb

Comment: I've use this before but didn't want to add another gem to my Gemfile if it wasn't necessary but this ended up working for me